# How to prevent a button appearing in index.html.erb if a condition has been met

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, I have this in Articles index.html.erb

```
<td><%= pluralize(article.likes.count, "like") %></td>
<td><%= button_to '+1', "/articles/#{article.id}/user/#{current_user.id}/like_vote", method: :post %></td>
```

But if a voter has already liked an article, how do I prevent the button from showing up in index.html.erb? Is there a simple way to prevent the button from showing up in index.html.erb?

This is the method in ArticlesController:

```
def like_vote
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @user_id = params[:user_id]
  likes = Like.where("user_id = ? and article_id = ?", @user_id, @article.id )

  if likes.blank?
    @article.likes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
  redirect_to(article_path)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails provides an `optimal way` i.e., `scope` which is a set of constraints on database interactions (such as a condition, limit, or offset) that are `chainable` and `reusable`.

Add a scope to `Like` model as below:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :voted_count, ->(user_id, article_id) { where("user_id = ? and article_id = ?", user_id, article_id).count }    
end
```

Update the view as below:

```
<td><%= pluralize(article.likes.count, "like") %></td>
<td><%= button_to('+1', "/articles/#{article.id}/user/#{current_user.id}/like_vote", method: :post) if Like.voted_count(current_user.id, article.id) == 0  %></td>
```

Comment: yeah, it did. Thank you. I really like the fact that you used scopes even though I don't understand them very well. They seem to be used all over the place.

Comment: Glad to help. :) you can read about scopes here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope

Comment: thank you. =) Would you know of any other resources on scopes though? Just asking. No worries if you can't answer. Just wondering.

Comment: No Problem. Refer to Rails Guide, they too have nice examples http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: thank you. =) if I may ask, how did you become so proficient in ruby on rails? I'm kinda struggling with it, and not really sure how to improve my way around ROR.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%-unless article.voted?(current_user)%>
<td><%= button_to '+1', "/articles/#{article.id}/user/#{current_user.id}/like_vote", method: :post %></td>
<%- end%>
```

and make a method in your articles  model

```
def voted?(user)
  self.likes.where(user_id:user.id).first.present?
end
```

Comment: I like this answer. It could also be written `self.likes.where(user_id: user.id).exists?`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in your index.html.erb...

`<td><%= pluralize(article.likes.count, "like") %></td>
<td><%= button_to '+1', "/articles/#{article.id}/user/#{current_user.id}/like_vote", method: :post if article.likes.present? %></td>`

Just include a the conditional statement at the end, and it will keep it from executing that line.